# Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence satisfying $|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq q|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$.Prove that $(x_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $q$ be a real number satisfying $0<q<1$. Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequence satisfying $$|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq q|x_n-x_{n-1}|$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N^+}$. Prove that $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence. I try to show that the sequence is Cauchy but I stuck at finding the $M$. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$|x_{n+1}-x_n| \leq q|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ for $m>n$ we have,

$|x_{m}-x_n| \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m}|x_k-x_{k-1}|\le \sum_{k=0}^{(m-n)}q^k|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|=|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\sum_{k=0}^{(m-n)}q^k<|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^k=\frac{1}{(1-q)}|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|<\frac{q^{n-1}}{1-q}|x_2-x_1|=cq^n,c=|x_2-x_1|/(q(1-q))$

Now its easy to show that it is a cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: note that for any $N$ and $n>N$, we have $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq q|x_n-x_{n-1}|\cdot q^{N-1}|x_2-x_1|$. This can be proven by induction on $N$. If we have $n>m>N$, then how can we bound $|x_n-x_m|$?